# Forget previous employers domain

Tags: windows-7, boot, domain, cmos

How can I get my laptop to forget the domain of my previous employer? This user account seems to be running some sort of batch file (which I can't find) to connect up to network drives and printers and the laptop has a boot protection password for the cmos.  I have access to the administrator account, which I want to make the default account, but every time I log on it defaults to the domain account and doesn't allow me to choose my administrator account before logging into Windows 7

Comment: Did you check MSConfig and Task Scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

1. For analysis of the automatically started Programs I would use
   [AutoRuns](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)
2. To get rid of the domain user you can just unjoin the computer form
   the domain. If the domain user you have doesn't have enough rights
   log in with the other one.

   - Go to C:\Windows\System32 and locate cmd.exe.
   - Right click it while holding shift choose: "Run as different user"
   - Enter .\ (The .\ tells it to use a local account) and your password.
   - Enter sysdm.cpl in the command window.
   - Click "Change" where it says "To rename this computer or change it's domain and workgroup click Change...".
   - Choose to join a Workgroup instead of a domain there (Name doesn't
       really matter, if your other computers have one take this or just
       take "WORKGROUP".
   - If you are prompted for Username and password chose any username (but
     insert at least one character if it is windows 7 in XP it would not
     matter) and now password. Please note that this is not reversable
     without domain admin probably).
   - Press OK and Reboot.
3. As for the BIOS password. Most of them can be resetted by using a
   certain jumper or removing the battery but it differs from model to
   model. (On some it might be non reversable). Google for "CLear BIOS
   Password " or something. However it shouldn't normally 
   be necessary to change the BIOS password for anything.